Is the following proof valid of $(x+y)^{p-1} \leq x^{p-1} + y^{p-1}$ for $p \in (0, 1)$.
It is well-known
$$(x+y)^p \leq x^p + y^p$$ when $p \in (0, 1)$. Does this hold when $p$ has a subtraction, ie
$$ (x+y)^{p-1} \leq x^{p-1} + y^{p-1}$$
I believe it is true and propose the following proof:
$$ (x+y)^{p-1} = (x+y)^p (x+y)^{-1} \leq (x^p+y^p) (x+y)^{-1} = x^p(x+y)^{-1} + y^p(x+y)^{-1} \leq x^p (x)^{-1} + y^p(y)^{-1} = x^{p-1} +y^{p-1}$$
Does this look correct? Do I need to assume either one of $x>0$, $y>0$ to avoid the $\infty$ issues? Perhaps not since $p \in (0, 1)$ non-inclusive as long as we let $c/0 = \infty$ for $c>0$.

You need to assume both $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ for $x^p$ and $y^p$ to make sense for real, possibly irrational $p$. Even with $p = 1/2$, you'd need to dip into complex numbers, and the inequality becomes meaningless. Otherwise, this looks good to me.
